# VCR with webmock blocking my rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, vcr, webmock

I have a problem with my vcr with webmock spec. I have all the time the same problem when i run rspec spec/

```
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/webmock-1.18.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:114:in `request': Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST https://somevalue@accounts.spotify.com/api/token with body 'grant_type=client_credentials' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*; q=0.5, application/xml', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length'=>'29', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'} (WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError)

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:post, "https://somevalue@accounts.spotify.com/api/token").
  with(:body => {"grant_type"=>"client_credentials"},
       :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*; q=0.5, application/xml', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length'=>'29', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

============================================================
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:186:in `block in transmit'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/webmock-1.18.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/webmock-1.18.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:182:in `transmit'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:68:in `execute'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:35:in `execute'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rest_client-1.8.2/lib/restclient.rb:73:in `post'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspotify-1.9.0/lib/rspotify/connection.rb:27:in `authenticate'
    from /home/pnc/sites/spolisty/config/initializers/devise.rb:260:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/devise-a9d90503e903/lib/devise.rb:293:in `setup'
    from /home/pnc/sites/spolisty/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/pnc/sites/spolisty/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pnc/sites/spolisty/spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/pnc/sites/spolisty/spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `require'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `block in requires='
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `requires='
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:103:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:102:in `each'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:102:in `process_options_into'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:95:in `setup'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/pnc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What i try to solve this problem:

1. Add  c.ignore_localhost = true to my vcr config
2. Add this code to my rails_helper.rb

   require 'webmock/cucumber'
   WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
3. I try remove all test where i use vcr and then run rspec spec/ but still this error appear
4. This error shows me that i can stub this request, but how can i do this?

Any idea how can i resolve this error?

Comment: It actually tells you how to stub the request.  Copy the text from "stub_request... " to "...:headers => {})" into your rspec tests.

https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

Comment: @Panchzo You seem to be under the impression that since you are running tests, it is all local. Nope, the tests are posting a request to `https://somevalue@accounts.spotify.com/api/token`, and that http request needs to be stubbed as mentioned by the message.

Comment: The whole purpose of VCR is to record a real HTTP request and then replay it when that exact same request is made again, so no manual stubbing is required. Could you please share your VCR configuration?

Comment: @Panczo Even I am facing the same issue. How did you solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'webmock'
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```

to very top of spec_helper.rb doesn't work when you use the spring gem which will be enabled by default in rails 4.1 to preload rspec
It will raise a `WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError` and break the test suit

Use a initializers:

```
# File: config/initializers/webmock.rb
if Rails.env.test?
  require 'webmock'
  WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

VCR should chime in when you run any spec that is making a HTTP request (whether or not you've wrapped it in a `use_cassette` block), so it looks like your config file is not getting picked up.  For example, if you have required your vcr config file, but haven't wrapped your test spec in a `use_cassette` block, you will get some output like:

```
VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:
An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:

There is currently no cassette in use. There are a few ways
   you can configure VCR to handle this request:
```

If your config file is `spec/spec_vcr.rb` make sure to add:

```
require 'spec_vcr'
```

to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` or `spec/rails_helper.rb` file.  Make sure not to call your config file `spec/vcr.rb` or there will be conflicts with the actual gem.